# How to initialize std::map<int, int> with key incrementing but same value?

Tags: c++

How can I initialize map such that key is 0 to 10 but every value is set to some int, say 100?

```
m[0] = 100;
m[1] = 100;
m[2] = 100;
...
```

Comment: Use a loop? Also is a map really the best choice here? Wouldn't a `std::vector` make more sense (unless you plan to make holes later on)

Comment: Write a loop. A garden variety loop. A simple `for` loop. Can't get anything simpler. One could, I suppose, get creative and use `std::generate`, if one's goal is to show off their expert C++ knowledge, but that won't really accomplish anything useful.

Comment: `std::vector<int> m( 10, 100 );`

Comment: Why are you using a `std::map` when your keys are continuous and starting from zero?

Comment: Guys we don't know how this map is going to be used post-initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really want a vector, which you can initialize to a default value like

```cpp
std::vector<int> m(10, 100);
```

If you really want to use a map, then you might use your good-old for-loop, like

```cpp
std::map<int, int> m;
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i){
  m[i] = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` doesn't provide such a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), but if you do it often enough that you need a quick way, a simple template function with a (for) loop should be enough:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


template <class T, class Y>
std::map<T, Y> get_map(T size, Y val)
{
  std::map<T, Y> m;
  for (T i = 0; i != size; ++i)
    m[i] = val;
  return m;
}

int main()
{
  auto m = get_map(10, 100);

  for (const auto& e : m)
    std::cout << e.first << " - " << e.second << '\n';
  std::cout << std::flush;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 - 100
1 - 100
2 - 100
3 - 100
4 - 100
5 - 100
6 - 100
7 - 100
8 - 100
9 - 100
```